# R: How to visualize large and clumped scatter plot

Tags: r, graphics

```
 status = sample(c(0, 1), 500, replace = TRUE)
 value = rnorm(500)

 plot(value)
 smoothScatter(value)
```

I'm trying to make a scatterplot of value, but if I were to just plot it, the data is all clumped together and it's not very presentable. I've tried smoothScatter(), which makes the plot look a bit nicer, but I am wondering if there's a way to color code the values based on the corresponding status?

I am trying to see if there's a relationship between status and value. What's another way to present the data nicely? I've tried boxplot, but I'm wondering how I can make the smoothScatter() plot better or if there are other ways to visualize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you meant to write `plot(status, value)` in your example?  Regardless, there's not going to be much *difference* using this data, but you should get the idea of things to maybe look at with the following examples...

Have you looked into `jitter`?

Some basics:

`plot(jitter(status), value)`

[image: Simple Jitter]

or perhaps `plot(jitter(status, 0.5), value)`

[image: Tighter Jitter Plot]

Fancier with package `ggplot2` you could do:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(value, status)
ggplot(data=df, aes(jitter(status, 0.10), value)) + 
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5)
```

[image: ggplot 01]

or this...

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(factor(status), value)) +
  geom_violin()
```

[image: ggplot 02]

or...

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=status, y=value)) +
  geom_density2d() + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-1,2))
```

[image: ggplot 03]

or...

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=status, y=value)) +
  geom_density2d() +
  stat_density2d(geom="tile", aes(fill = ..density..), contour=FALSE) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-1,2))
```

[image: ggplot 04]

or even this..

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(fill=factor(status), value)) +
  geom_density(alpha=0.2)
```

[image: ggplot 05]